# MySQL, Foreign Key contraint fails in SP, but not when executing manually

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

the task I am executing seems so simple. But this behaviour is very creepy indeed.
I am using MySQL.

I am having a Table for uploaded files - containing ID, FileName, FileHash, UploadDate, UploadUser etc.
Basically, these are XML Files.

And I have also a Table, containing the contents of the uploaded files. XML Files get parsed when uploaded and the contents are written into this Table.
This table has a reference, a foreign key, to the File-Table.

Here is the definition (shortened to the crucial points):

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_xmlfiles` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Filename` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `FileHash` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UploadDate` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Status` enum('uploaded','closed','error','archived') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'uploaded',
  `ScanID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=986 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci COMMENT='Stores all uploaded xmlfiles data';


CREATE TABLE `tbl_xmlcontents` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FileID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FileID` (`FileID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fileID` FOREIGN KEY (`FileID`) REFERENCES `tbl_xmlfiles` (`ID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=304817 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci COMMENT='Stores all xml content data';
```

For better understanding, a "Scan" bundles multiple XML Files together.

I understand of course, that, if a File from the File Table is to be deleted, we first have to delete the rows from the other table (because this is no CASCADE contraint, which i do not want).
This is what I do in the SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_DeleteFilesByScanID`(
    IN ScanID INT,
    IN username VARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN
    ...
    DELETE c FROM tbl_xmlcontents c LEFT JOIN tbl_xmlfiles f ON c.FileID=f.ID WHERE f.`ScanID`=ScanID;
    DELETE FROM tbl_xmlfiles WHERE `ScanID`=ScanID;
    ...
END
```

Running this SP, it errors:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`MYGREATTOOL`.`tbl_xmlcontents`, CONSTRAINT `fileID` FOREIGN KEY (`FileID`) REFERENCES `tbl_xmlfiles` (`ID`))
```

It errors on the second statement "DELETE FROM tbl_xmlfiles ...". The first one is executed as expected.

BUT here comes the clue.
When I execute these two DELETE-lines manually in MySQL Workbench (replacing the ScanID parameter with a valid value) - all works as expected. How can that be, for heaven's sake?

Can you please help me?

Greetings, xola

Comment: Qualify the column in the second statement: `... tbl_xmlfiles.ScanID = ScanID`. Otherwise you just delete all the rows.

Comment: errr... right... that was my failure. Sure, always ScanID==ScanID. But how can that be? I mean, aren't the ticks like ` ` saying "this is a field name"?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, sticky bit's comment pointed me to the right solution. Thank you very much!

When specifying the `ScanID` with the table name/alias, then it is not considered as the SP Parameter "ScanID", but as a field name.

Solution:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_xmlfiles x WHERE x.`ScanID`=ScanID;
```

Can someone clarify, why the MySQL Parser thinks, that "`ScanID`" (sorry, here are backticks around the word - Stackoverflow makes this a quote automatically) is the SP Parameter? Aren't Backticks always meant to describe a MySQL field name?